# What are the first mission rewards or penalties?

Tags: band-of-blades

In the After the Mission section of each Chosen, after answering initial question we are told to continue with the bookkeeping phase.

> After selecting Roles and answering their initial questions, proceed with the bookkeeping step of the mission phase.

This confuses me, because for me, answering the initial questions means the rewards and penalties are already done. Moreover, the starting morale is already penalized by the death of members, if I do the bookkeeping step, does that mean the morale is penalized twice, only for this first mission?

I can't find the actual reward or penalty of the first mission in the Chosen section, so **what are the rewards or penalties of the first mission?** Where it is stated, other than in the initial question?

Answer (score 2):

### The first mission's bookkeeping is baked into setup.

I can see there being confusion whichever way they tried to go with it, but if it helps you to think of it as an initial setup + some mission rewards and penalties to apply during bookkeeping along with marking off morale for deaths, here you go.

#### Universal Setup

**The Commander**: 0 Pressure, 3 Time, 0 Intel.

**The Marshal**: 7 Morale.

**The Quartermaster**: 2 Supply, no materiel.

#### Shreya's Starting Mission

**Mission Rewards**: +1 Morale, -1 Time.

**Mission Penalties**: +2 Pressure, +1 Time.

**Always**: An enemy Infamous is destroyed.

#### The Horned One's Starting Mission

**Mission Rewards**: +2 Morale, Asset: +Black Shot

**Mission Penalties**: +1 Pressure, Shortage: Black Shot (4-tick)

**Always**: +1 Intel

#### Zora's Starting Mission

**Mission Rewards**: +2 Morale

**Mission Penalties**: +1 Pressure, 1 Death (Commander)

**Always**: +1 Chosen Favor.